# Display KML file data in a table

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, kml

I have a KML file and I would like to display its content in a table including the coordinates. I don't want to display it in a map, but just to get the information in the file. 
Is there a Library or a way to do that in Javascript ? 
I already tried using kmlappparser, while it does display *some* of the information, it doesn't show all the attributes (coordinates...)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display it as xml or extract the coordinates from the kml?

Comment: I want to extract the coordinates with all the others attributes as well.
But displaying it as XML will do the trick too, I can format it then.

Comment: What does your code look like where you attempted to display the coordinates?  What does the KML file you are trying to parse look like?

Comment: I don't have a specific KML file I want to display, the user is supposed to be able to select a file from his computer, then display it.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively looking for a KML parser.

You can use [kmlappparser](https://code.google.com/p/kmlmapparser/) for that purpose.

Comment: I already tried kmlappparser, while it does display some of the information, it doesn't show the coordinates.

Comment: In that case I suggest you edit your question to be more specific. Say you are looking for a kml and that you already tried kmlappparser.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the kml file into a .csv, then create a table from the csv.
Use gpsbabel. There is a python module for gpsbabel, or you can install gpsbabel from http://www.gpsbabel.org/ . GPS babel has a GUI or you can run it from the command line.
if you run GPSbabel from the command line your script should look something like this

```
gpsbabel -i kml -f input.kml csv -F output.csv
```